# javascript not working as expected in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

i have a simple JavaScript that works in all major browsers except Firefox (26)...i've looked around and cant find a reason why it wont work

its intended to change the the style.left of an element, it will work the first time but not more than once in Firefox. it will work fine in all other browsers i have tried. this is a stripped down version of the script, in case any one spots unused variables etc.

here is a copy of the incomplete JavaScript and html that goes with it

a working jsfiddle as requested...jsfiddle.net/zvSMa/1

**JavaScript:**

```
var left;

function scroll_left(direction){
 left = parseInt(document.getElementById("body").offsetLeft,10);


if (left == -2868) {
return;
 }else{
      switch(left){
           case -1:                  
                stop = -955;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);
               left=-955;
                break;
           case 0:                  
                stop = -955;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);

                break;
           case -955:
                stop = -1910;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);
                break;
           case -1910:
                stop = -2865;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);


                break;
           case -2865:               
                break;
           }
      }
}


function smooth_scroll(current,stop){
 document.getElementById("body").style.left= stop+"px";
 left = parseInt(document.getElementById("body").offsetLeft,10);
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = current;
 document.getElementById("dummy2").innerHTML = stop;


}

function scroll_right(direction){
 left = parseInt(document.getElementById("body").offsetLeft,10);


if (left == 2868) {
      return;
 }else{
      switch(left){
           case -1:                  

                break;
           case 0:                  


                break;
           case -955:
                stop = -0;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);
                break;
           case -1910:
                stop = -955;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);


                break;
           case -2865:
                stop = -1910;
                smooth_scroll(left,stop);

                break;
           }
      }
}
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>   
<!--Advanced Design and Solutions-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Under Construction
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <meta name="author" content="Advanced Design And Solutions">
    <meta name="description" content="x">
    <meta name="keywords" content="x">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="banner">
            <a class="title_logo" href="index.php">
                Advanced Design and Solutions
            </a>
            <div id="links">
                <a class="banner_content" id="on" href="web%20design.php">Web Design</a><a class="banner_content" href="marketing%20material%20design.php">Marketing Material</a><a class="banner_content" href="logo%20design.php">Logo Design</a><a class="banner_content" href="business%20card%20design.php">Business Card Design</a>
            </div>

            <div id="email_panel">
                <form class="" action="MAILTO:contact@advanceddesignandsolutions.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                    <fieldset class="contact">
                        <legend><span class="page_text text_spacing">Send us an Email at contact@AdvancedDesignandSolutions.com</span></legend>
                        <p class="page_text text_spacing">
                            Please fill out this short form and we will get back to you as soon as possible with a reply.
                        </p>

                            <input type="radio" name="product" value="Web Design">Web Design <input type="radio" name="product" value="Marketing Materials">Marketing Materials <input type="radio" name="product" value="Logos">Logos <input type="radio" name="product" value="Business Cards">Business Cards <input type="radio" name="product" value="Other">Other
                        <br>
                        <label class="page_text">Name: <input class="alignment" type="text" name="client" required="required" placeholder="FIRST AND LAST NAME"></label> <!--label with input-->
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <label class="page_text">Email: <input class="alignment" type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="ADDRESS@EXAMPLE.COM"></label><br>
                        <br>
                        <label class="page_text">Tel: <input class="alignment" id="phoneinput" type="tel" required="required" name="Phone"></label><br>
                        <label class="page_text">Inquiry: 
                        <textarea class="" type="text" name="" required="required">
</textarea></label><br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"> <input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="hider">
                <div id="l_arrow" onclick="scroll_left(-2);">
                    &laquo;
                </div>
                <div id="r_arrow" onclick="scroll_right(2);">
                    &raquo;
                </div>
                <div id="body">
                    <div id="content_pane_1">
                        <h2>
                            Web Design
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            A website is an important marketing and informational tool for you and your business. Your website can be used for various purposes, to define your company's brand, to advertise promotional sales or discounts, to give an insight or introduction into your company. No matter what purpose you have in mind for your site, we would be glad to take the website journey with you!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content_pane_2">
                        <h2>
                            Marketing Materials
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            We design marketing materials in any shape and size, such as promotional pamphlets, tri-fold brochures, door hangers, as well as anything else you can think up. We enjoy helping your business come up with creative, clever and professional marketing materials. We also provide competitively priced printing services for your designs.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content_pane_3">
                        <h2>
                            Logo Design
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            A logo is an integral part of your company's brand or image. It serves to identify your company's product or service. Proper branding can result in higher sales for the products you sell because of brand loyalty. A well thought out branding with a quality logo can allow you to shape how your company is viewed i.e., youthfulness, fun or luxury. If you are looking to create an image for your company or re-branding your existing business, we look forward to putting our creativity to work for you!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content_pane_4">
                        <h2>
                            Business Card Design
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            A business card is often part of the first contact that you will have with your potential client or customer. So it is invaluable that you make a good first impression. A quality designed and printed business card will help you establish your the image of quality and professionalism. When it come time to design you business card or reprint your existing design, we wont be beat on quality or service!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="dummy"></div><div id="dummy2"></div>
            </div>          <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer_topline"></div>
            <a class="footer_links" href="index.php">Home</a><a class="footer_links" href="web%20design.php">Web Design</a><a class="footer_links" href="marketing%20material%20design.php">Marketing Material Design</a><a class="footer_links" href="logo%20design.php">Logo Design</a><a class="footer_links" href="business%20card%20design.php">Business Card Design</a><a class="footer_links" href="index.php">&#169; Copyright  <?php echo date("Y") ?></a>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: none. if i was getting errors it would give me a place to start.

Comment: What does it not do in FireFox what it should do?

Comment: on the click it should change the style.left. it will do that in firefox but only once. it should do it on subsequent clicks also

Comment: A working JSFiddle would go a long way to making it easier for others to debug.

Comment: a working jsfiddle as requested...http://jsfiddle.net/zvSMa/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by digging into what firefox is doing in response to the javascript i discovered that it responds differently. where all the other browsers would change the style.left to match what i specified firefox instead starts at -1 for offsetleft where all others start at 0 making all the switch cases wrong.